# firebase uid becomes undefined after refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase

So the question is the pretty much the title, the user unique id becomes undefined after a page is refreshed or different page is loaded. Although I can still use other user data such as name or email.

```
  signinBut.addEventListener("click", e => {
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  user = result.user;

}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  var email = error.email;
  var credential = error.credential;
});
```

});

Here is the function that writes the user object.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you always get the correct sign-in state for the user, [attach a listener to `onAuthStateChanged` as shown in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user). You'd use this *instead* of your current `then()` callback, so:

```
signinBut.addEventListener("click", e => {
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    var email = error.email;
    var credential = error.credential;
  });
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  user = result.user;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After successful signIn your user is stored in `firebase.auth().currentUser` variable. [Read official doc about managing user in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).
Currently when you page is loaded you do signIn and stores user to local variable. After refreshing a page your user is removed - that is why he is undefined. All you need to do is get user from `currentUser` and check if it is null of not. `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` will help you at this.

Comment: I am getting user from firebase.auth().currentUser now, although it gives user uid as undefined still. Do I redefine the user when the user gets checked in firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...) observer?

Comment: Frank van Puffelen show an example of using onAuthStateChanged :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case when this happened I used an AuthGaurd such that the component is only allowed to load when the service is initiated completely.

In  AppModule.ts file for the component route the auth-gaurd was added :

```
{path : 'view', component : ViewDetailsComponent, canActivate : [ViewDetailsGaurd]}
```

Now in the ViewDetailsGaurd.ts which is the guard service :

```
canActivate() : Observable<boolean> {
   return this.authService.isInitCmpleted();
 }
```

And in the AuthenticationService.ts :

```
isInitCmpleted() : Observable<boolean> {
   return Observable.of(this.isServiceLoaded);
}
```